# Getting Node to 'understand' ES6 import (Babel)

Tags: node.js, express, import, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Trying to run my express server and it can't understand the 'import' keyword. I thought I'd installed all the Babel dependencies but obviously not...

Command: `node server.js`

Console: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`

---

**.babelrc** - do I need to add anything else to this?

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
...

"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }

...
```

**server.js**

```
import path from 'path'
import Express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import counterApp from './reducers'
import App from './containers/App'

const app = Express()
const port = 3000

// This is fired every time the server side receives a request
app.use(handleRender)

import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'

function handleRender(req, res) {
  // Create a new Redux store instance
  const store = createStore(counterApp)

  // Render the component to a string
  const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  )

  // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
  const preloadedState = store.getState()

  // Send the rendered page back to the client
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState))
}

function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="root">${html}</div>
        <script>
          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ${JSON.stringify(preloadedState)}
        </script>
        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `
}

app.listen(port)
```

---

### UPDATE

Have now done the following:

Command: `npm install babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"]
}
```

Command: `babel server.js --out-file server-compiled.js`

Command: `node server-compiled.js`

--> The compilation of `server.js` seems to have worked. I still get the same error message, but this time for the file `./containers/App.ks`, which also contains an ES6 module statement.

I have included all the babel plugins and presets in my `webpack.config.js` file so I would have assumed that my bundling took care of all the other files?

**server-compiled.js**

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var Express = require('express');
var React = require('react');
var redux = require('redux').createStore;
var Provider = require('react-redux').Provider;
var counterApp = require('./reducers');
var App = require('./containers/App');

var app = Express();
var port = 3000;

// This is fired every time the server side receives a request
app.use(handleRender);

var renderToString = require('react-dom/server').renderToString;

function handleRender(req, res) {
  // Create a new Redux store instance
  var store = createStore(counterApp);

  // Render the component to a string
  var html = renderToString('\n    <Provider store={store}>\n      <App />\n    </Provider>\n    ');

  // Grab the initial state from our Redux store
  var preloadedState = store.getState();

  // Send the rendered page back to the client
  res.send(renderFullPage(html, preloadedState));
}

function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) {
  return ' <!doctype html>\n    <html>\n      <head>\n        <title>Redux Universal Example</title>\n      </head>\n      <body>\n        <div id="root">' + html + '</div>\n        <script>\n          window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ' + JSON.stringify(preloadedState) + '\n        </script>\n        <script src="/static/bundle.js"></script>\n      </body>\n    </html>\n    ';
}

app.listen(port);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./client.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
            {
               test: /\.js$/,
               exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
               loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a valid name to reference
               query: {
                  presets: ['es2015', 'react'],
                  plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']
               }
            }
        ]
```

**client.js** (entry file)

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import App from './containers/App'
import counterApp from './reducers'

// Grab the state from a global injected into server-generated HTML
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__

// Create Redux store with initial state
const store = createStore(counterApp, preloadedState)

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**containers/App.js** - this file still brings up error in console

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>App Component Here</div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: es6 modules are not part of es6 https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/

Comment: So are you saying that you can only use `const express = require('express')`, for example?

Comment: You can simply add "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs" to your .babelrc.  The reason it's not included is because es6 modules are defined by es6, but their implementation is still pending.

Comment: Please see update...

Answer (score 3):

It's not enough to install Babel and create a `.babelrc` file. You have to actually compile your file and run the compiled file with `node`.

You can compile your file using this command:

```
babel server.js --out-file server-compiled.js
```

And then run it:

```
node server-compiled.js
```

---

To compile entire directory, use this command:

```
babel src --out-dir lib
```

Replace `src` with the name of the directory where you keep your source files, and `lib` with the name of the directory where you would like to output the compiled files.

---

See also [Babel CLI docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/).

Comment: Tried that, and it still says `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`, but this time on the `import React...` line for some reason.

Comment: @Paulos3000 How does the compiled file look like?

Comment: @Paulos3000 did you ever solved it?  I'm having the same problem

Comment: @intercoder If this answer doesn't help you, you should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue and solved by using `babel-node` instead of node. I'm using Webstorm and it was easy just to change the node interpreter by looking at the node_packages (or if you have it installed globally at `~\AppData\Roaming\npm\babel-node.cmd` in Windows and `~/.node/bin/babel-node` *nix/osx. By the way, in Windows important to use the `*.cmd`.

Comment: Note that `babel-node` is intended to be used only in development, not in production.